# How to plot points over a line in python using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Lets say i have a calibration line made using matplotlib. How do i plot points over this line?

I currently have this calibration line:

[image: calibration line]

and i want to add 3 points with values 2.02, 2,09 and 2,26. 
When i use `plt.scatter(["U1","U2","U3"], ["2.02", "2,09", "2,26"]`

i end up with this (notice how the y-axis scale is changed and the original calibration line is not accurate anymore)

[image: plot]

Any idea how to fix this?

The plot is made using the following code:

```
    if unknown == "no":
        plt.plot(fixed_list, y)
    else:
        plt.plot(fixed_list, y, zorder=1 )
        plt.scatter(["U1", "U2", "U3"], u_means, zorder=2)
    plt.ylabel("Mean (GRN)")
    plt.xlabel("Sample")
    plt.title(name)
    plt.show()
```

I plot a list of sample names on the x axis (fixed_list), and a list of values (y) on the y-axis. U_means is a list containing the points y-coordinates to be plotted.

Comment: It would be helpful it you posted a more complete example, showing the code that plotted the calibration line and how you have created the figure and axes. At first glance, it appears that the line was plotted with X-axis values that were numbers. But then when you go to add your points you are passing in a list of string objects as your X values. So matplotlib is confused as to where to put them and is attaching them to the end of the X-axis. I would use the actual X axis values that go with your Y-axis values instead.

Comment: what are `"U1","U2","U3"`?